# Adding EMA to alert query

Tags: alert, pine-script, trend

A quick fix for someone with more knowledge than me. I have made an alert for pinbars, but I only want them to show if they are above the EMA20 line.

```
//Alert

aboveema = abs(close-open) > ema(close,20)

pinbarup = upshadow>body?prevc>pbody?(close[1]>open[1]?(body[1]>body?(high>high[1]?(upshadow>0.5*body?(upshadow>2*downshadow?1:0):0):0):0):0):0:0 and aboveema

alertcondition(pinbarup, title="PinbarUp", message="PinbarUp")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should already do that, as you have the `aboveema` condition at the end of your `pinbarup` condition. This version is functionally equivalent but uses `and` to join your conditions, so eliminates the need for the ternaries:

```
pinbarup = upshadow > body and prevc > pbody and close[1] > open[1] and body[1] > body and high > high[1] and upshadow > 0.5 * body and upshadow > 2 * downshadow and aboveema
```